# jQuery css doesn't set all properties on img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an img element that I am trying to set css properties for with the following code:

```
var image = smallImageData.clone().css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':(galleryBB['w'] - w)/2 + 'px',
    'top':((galleryBB['h']-6) - h)/2 + 'px',
    'width':w + 'px',
    'height':h + 'px'
});
```

Where smallImageData is an <img> element. However, sometimes, but not always not all of the css properties are set. Specifically, position is correctly set to 'absolute', but left,top, width, and height are not set at all. I have put a log statements before and after this statement and verified that this is in fact the culprit (i.e. jQuery is never setting the properties, they aren't being unset somewhere else).

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: If some of your variables are not set properly you might result in setting things like "undefinedpx" which probably does not have any effect. Sure they are all set at this point?

Comment: Try putting the settings object in a variable and using `console.log(settings)`, to confirm that it has all the values you expect.

Comment: @cshuff, you were right, it looks like w and h are NaN when it happens. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Now to figure out why they are NaN :(